# Wordpress: Set parent dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, parent

My pages on my wordpress page work fine and are accessible via the following example links:

```
example.com/images
example.com/videos
example.com/others
```

What I'm trying to do now is to create a "download" page that sets each page manually as a child. So when I go on

```
example.com/download
```

I can access the above pages so my url becomes the following:

```
example.com/download/images
example.com/download/videos
example.com/download/others
```

Is that possible and if yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: Create download as parent page and others child of it.

Comment: very true but then they would always have the download page as a parent. I only want them to have a parent once you go to example.com/download